# Is it possible to have two seperate Carts on WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a custom WooCommerce Cart. It would have the same capabilities as the real WooCommerce Cart. The only difference would be that in each cart, only specific types of products can go in.

Let's say I have a session variable that tells me which products to show. And based on that session variable, I add products to a specific cart. And you can always change that session variable but keep the products for each cart until the session ends.

After that, I go to the checkout and it will list items from the specific cart based on that session variable once again.

Is something like that possible, specifically having two separate WooCommerce carts, the default one and a new custom one?

I tried this:

```
if (! isset(WC()->cart_custom) || '' === WC()->cart_custom) {
    WC()->cart_custom = new WC_Cart();
}
```

but every time I add products to the default cart and open the default cart page, the default cart is emptied. I don't know why.

I hope my question makes some sense.

Comment: `WC()->cart_custom = new WC_Cart();` - just because you add your own property to the current `WC` instance, does not mean this will get persisted anywhere. As soon as you make the next request to navigate to another page, this property will in all likelihood not exist any more. I guess you'd have to persist the `WC_Cart` instance you are creating there into the session yourself, and then re-assign at the proper moment ...

Comment: @CBroe I understand that. My initial plan was to copy almost every function of WooCommerce where WC()->cart is mentioned, but that would be too much work and the same as creating a custom, non-woocommerce, cart from scratch. I was hoping that I could somehow create a new WC_Cart instance and use it separately.

Comment: You'd have to find the right moment/places to do this, so that WooCommerce doesn't create one itself already, but uses your instance.

Comment: Ok, does anyone know right moment/places to do this?

Comment: Did you manage to do this? The shop I'm building is selling products like wine bottles and take-away dishes. The dishes are only delivered through pickup at the store location, whereas wine can either be picked up or use a delivery service. If the customer is buying a mixture of things it gets complicated: since the delivery is different they must be handled through separate checkouts (which I don't know how to do), but it would be even better to use separate carts, and let the user select which one to check out.

Comment: @ChristerFernstrom Yes, but I did not use WooCommerce functionalities for the custom cart. Instead, I created custom functions that "duplicate" WooCommerce flow but are much simpler. And had to override some of the WooCommerce functions to have pretty much the same flow for both default and custom card and checkout process.

Comment: OK, I'm glad you found a way to do it. What I'm thinking of is to set up a number of virual carts in the form of "containers", and to change the "put in cart" function to send the selected product(s) to one of the virtual carts instead of the Woo cart. Then when the user requests to view the cart, (s)he would have to choose which virtual cart to use and then I will just copy the virtual cart contents into the Woo cart. From then on everything will be handled the normal way by Woocommerce (coupons, shipping, checkout,..)

Comment: @ChristerFernstrom That is great idea. For me, the custom cart did not have a payment at the end, so it was a different situation. The default cart is for regular shopping, and the virtual (custom) cart is for the user to "sell" his products to the webshop, like a form that looks like the WooCommerce checkout.